# How do I organize my project files and directories to be put to svn and back?

Tags: svn, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would you organize a Subversion repository for in house software projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217/how-would-you-organize-a-subversion-repository-for-in-house-software-projects)

Hi,

This is the svn question regarding the big projects and many directories in it.

I'm new to svn but I googled for one simple answer and didn't find it: How do I organize my project files and directories to be put to svn and back? Or there is other solution to my question?

My project consists of these: php, java, action script and MySQL. As you can see these are totally separate entities. Reorganizing it into one directory during devlopment, in order to put it to svn, seems to make a mess in my project.

Are there any best practices on how to manage this?

Notice! English is not my native language.

Chris

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217/how-would-you-organize-a-subversion-repository-for-in-house-software-projects or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872103/how-to-organize-project-directories-for-svn

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout any folder from svn to any location on your hard drive. You may use folder structure that you will, just need to know where is your project directories.
Generally is comfortable to have one folder for one project.

Answer (score 0):

If it really is a single project, then they're not at all as unrelated as you say: they're all parts of a common whole, and won't make sense without each other.

The typical structure for a Subversion repository has a project root, let's call it *project/*, under which all files for that single project reside.

To support tagging and branches, two sub directories are often created for these; that gives us *project/tags/* and *project/branches*. Finally, to have a tidy place to hold the latest current version, a directory called *project/trunk/* is typically used.

You would place your various bits and pieces under the *project/trunk/* directory, probably ending up with *project/trunk/php/*, *project/trunk/java/* and so on.

A checkout of trunk would look like

```
$ svn co /path/to/repo/project/trunk project/
```

This would give you a working directory called just *project/*, that would hold the trunk versions of all the language-specific sub-directories and their files.